# Keep getting a EOFError

Tags: python, calculator, eoferror

EOFError input message pops up while trying to run a calculator code. It's for an assignment and the defined function is necessary.

```
from math import *


def calculate(rlist):
    output = list()
    for j in range(len(rlist)):
        s = round(rlist[j] ** 2 * pi, 2)
        output.append(s)
    print(output)


r = list(map(float, input().split()))
calculate(r)
```

Comment: what's the exact error? What line is the error on?

Comment: It works for me. (in IDLE and the cli)

Comment: Works for me as well

Comment: How exactly are you running this code?  Are you running it directly on the command line, or using an IDE, or using an online code submission service, or something else?

Comment: If you run that from a command line and then type Ctrl-D whilst waiting for input you'll get EOFError